# Upgrade glibc with no root

Tags: linux, python-3.x, tensorflow, centos, virtualenv

I've been trying to get tensor flow to run on my university's cluster without much success. I've surmised that the cluster is running CentOS 6, though I guess some parts are running CentOS 7.

I had a lot of trouble installing python packages because of permissions issues. I was able to solve this by using virtualenv, which turned out to be exactly perfect for what I wanted to do.

Now, I have tensor flow installed. But, when I try to import it into python, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ugrad/marsden/virt_env/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/ugrad/marsden/virt_env/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/ugrad/marsden/virt_env/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ugrad/marsden/virt_env/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/ugrad/marsden/virt_env/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/ugrad/marsden/virt_env/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/ugrad/marsden/virt_env/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)
```

From the last line, I surmised that CentOS has too old a version of GLIBC. There's plenty of stuff on stack exchange about upgrading GLIBC, but the again we run into the permissions issues.

What I would like is to be install or compile an upgraded version of GLIBC in a separate directory, and then be able to use it in my virtual environment. Is this possible, and if so what do I need to do for it?

If my question does not make sense or more details are needed, please let me know.

Comment: Did you consider asking help from your sysadmin (or teacher)?

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow do exist as docker images. Does the University allow you to use docker? - if so, then this would be the easiest solution.

If you can't use docker images, I would look at virtualization, and if that's not an option I would look at maybe creating a chroot environment or using environment-modules to direct the OS to read glibc from the correct location. You should be able to compile glibc with --prefix=/your/home/directory, but you might have to compile some dependencies first.